# Why is not jthread::get_stop_source const?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdthread

The question says it. [[thread.jthread.stop]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.jthread.class#thread.jthread.stop-1) says:

> ```
> [[nodiscard]] stop_source get_stop_source() noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Equivalent to: `return ssource`;

Why is it not a pure observer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `stop_source` object allows you to request that the thread which has such an object (or its attendant `stop_token`) perform a stop. Such a request is not *logically* `const`. As such, if you fetch a `stop_source` for a `jthread`, it is expected that you are going to perform the aforementioned "not logically `const`" operation.

So the function you used to retrieve it is not `const`. Note that getting a `stop_token` *is* `const`, as this is an observer of thread-safe state, not a modifier of it.